# Copying columns values from one dataframe into another dataframe in Spark + Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jvm

I would like to merge 2 spark dataframes (scala). The first data frame contains only 1 row. The second dataframe has multiple rows. I would like to merge these and copy the address / phone column values in the first dataframe to all the rows in second dataframe. Is there a way do it using Spark operations?

**DF1**

```
name age address phone
ABC  25  XYZ     00000
```

**DF2**

```
    name   age

    Bill   30
    Steve  40
    Jackie 50
```

**Final DF**

```
name  age address phone
ABC    25  XYZ     00000
Bill   30  XYZ     00000
Steve  40  XYZ     00000
Jackie 50  XYZ     00000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

val row = df1.select("address", "phone").collect()(0)
val finalDF = df2.withColumn("address", lit(row(0)))
       .withColumn("phone", lit(row(1))).union(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple left `.join` by `name` with `df2` on the left side (with `age` which you get from `df1`):

```
val results = df2.select("name", "address", "phone")
              .join(df1, Seq("name"), "left")
```